# A name for our chat

Tags: discussion

Other Stack Exchange sites often have a clever name for their main chat room. For example Code Review has "The 2nd Monitor" and Programming Puzzles and Code Golf has "The Nineteenth Byte".

What should we call our Worldbuilding chat?

Comment: Don't forget that each chat room has a description next to the name. For example, the description for "The 2nd Monitor" is `General discussion about Code Review -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com`; ours could certainly be similar.

Comment: This question was asked early in beta and at the time we didn't rename the room.  A [new question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/what-should-the-name-of-our-chat-be) has been asked after deciding to rename it, so I'm closing this one.

Answer (score 11):

"White Mice Lounge" in reference to Douglas Adam's Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy, where the white mice are credited with creating earth.

Comment: I like this idea, assuming that it doesn't infringe on any rights. Couple it with a room description like "General worldbuilding discussions" or something like that, and I think it will be both a nice touch as well as discoverable.

Answer (score 11):

Following on from @MontyWild 's Douglas Adams suggestion what about

> The Factory Floor?

From Slartibartfast line to Arthur "Welcome to our factory floor" (where they build the planets).

WoldBuilding: The Factory Floor

Comment: I think [wold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold) building has a slightly narrower scope than worldbuilding ;)

Comment: (I was about to edit the typo but then I thought it would be funnier to leave it as is...)

Answer (score 9):

As I just got the Room Owner mantle automagically appointed me, I'm going with **Worldbuilders' General Chat** for now. Reasoning: It's obvious what SE it attaches to without being confusingly similar to the SE main site's name.

I *like* the idea of a more "clever" name, and will occasionally return to this space to see what the gestalt thinks up as our site's identity congeals.

Comment: We appear to have picked a name.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the best name our chat could have is the one it already has - ["Worldbuilding"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilding). This makes it immediately obvious that it is the right chat room and helps ensure new users can find the chat and participate as early as possible. I think our community will benefit from maximising communication with new users.

Comment: While this is clear I don't like it since then our chat and our site would have the same name.  That could be confusing and redundant.

Comment: @Vulcronos I don't understand how having the same name for the chat room and the Q&A site is confusing. Quite the contrary, figuring out that the chat room for Worldbuilding is “White Mice Lounge” or vice versa is a source of confusion.

Comment: @Gilles It is probably my background as a computer programmer and a hatred of naming conflicts.  White Mice Lounge, while amusing isn't descriptive enough for me.  That is why I suggested World Architects or World Blueprinting.  It isn't great but just changing the name up a bit makes me happy.

Comment: @Vulcronos Ah, a programmer. Chat room names and site names live in different namespaces, and are not automatically synchronized (unlike main and meta sites, whose names are synchronized). However, the convention to use the same names makes it a lot less confusing, because you can tell instantly which chat room is associated with which site. Amusing names have to be really worth it.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for explaining.  I can see worldbuilding working then.

Answer (score 4):

"The Drawing Board" in the metaphorical sense as used in "back to the drawing board".

Answer (score 2):

In reference to the Matrix: "The Architect's Room".

Answer (score 0):

To carry on with the Douglas Adams quotes begun by MadMAxJr, the white mice may have *commissioned* Earth, but Magrathea actually *built* it.

So, "The Magrathean Watercooler"

Comment: I like the idea, but I think that's a little too far-fetched.

Comment: Also the workplace is "The Watercooler", I don't know if it was your intention but I'd rather avoid the conflict.

Comment: Why not just *Magrathea?*

Answer (score 0):

"[Reticulating Splines](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Reticulating_splines)"

Answer (score 0):

**The Demiurges’ Lounge** (or something else involving demiurges)

I will leave it to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demiurge) to explain the concept of the *demiurge,* which fits worldbuilding very well in my opinion. While a concept of gnosticism, which can be considered a religion, I would be surprised if anybody were offended by this.

Answer (score -3):

I think something like World Architects or Blueprinting for Worlds could work.

Maybe even Fictional Realities or something along those lines.

Answer (score -5):

"the first day" As i just said on the Chat in reference to the bible "at the first day, god made the earth". would be controversy but also a bit funny.

Comment: We should be **very careful** with anything that can be construed as a religious reference. Stack Exchange has users literally from all over the world, observing (and not observing) a significant number of different religions. We do *not* want to turn people off by implying a particular religious slant on the site.

Comment: +1 for @MichaelKjörling i know that this would be very harsh (only god makes worlds) but i still find it funny.

Comment: I'm sure some Christian's might find it offensive, but honestly, as a pretty devout Christian, I find the cultural nod to be not at all offensive.  It isn't like it is a bad light, it's just making reference to a famous world creator.  That said, I'd be more inclined to the white mice since I love Hitchhikers Guide.

Comment: did the islam not have the same story of alah build the earth?

Comment: @Fulli - yeah, I think they do, but I can't speak for how they would react (or Jews for that matter).

Comment: The reference is an Abrahamic one, so reflects the creation story of islam, judaism and christianity. The possible offence or even just feeling of unwelcomeness (which we really want to avoid) would be for other beliefs, such as unrelated religions or atheism.