# Should we name our chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

In [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/a-name-for-our-chat) many suggestion were made for the name of our chat. These ranged from clever hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy references to simple and plain ideas. I'm asking a different, equally, if not more important question; **Should** we name our chat? If we choose to give it a name, then we have no short supply of suggestions from our great users. So, should we give our chat a name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Background info for ease of access...**

During the original review of this idea the site was still really new and the conclusion, if I recall correctly (someone correct me if I am off base here) was that we wanted to keep the name simple and obvious *for the time being* so people could find it and know what it was.

I supported that idea at the time.

---

Ok now that the history lesson is done I would have to say that I think the site is well enough established and we are good about pointing new users to the chat room via comments.  So...

**Yes.** We should come up with a new name for the chat room.

I would suggest a new meta question be posted asking for name ideas since the regular members of the site have changed a bit here and there and we want newer members to have the opportunity to contribute.

Comment: I agree with a new meta thread.  Repeating past suggestions is fine, but people's opinions might have changed in the almost two years since we last talked about this, and we should start fresh on voting.