# Runoff voting for the name of our chat

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

A [few weeks ago](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/should-we-name-our-chat) it was asked if we should name our chat. Since then [another question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/what-should-the-name-of-our-chat-be) was asked asking for suggestions to be used for voting and as of now, 10 suggestions have been made. Half of which are negative voted.

The top two suggestions from the previous question will be listed below as answers (with the posters reasoning behind it) to be used for voting.

A week will pass by and the top post will become our chats new name.

- **Please cast only one up-vote.  Down-votes will not be counted.**
- **Please note that suggestions for names are no longer being taken, we are simply voting on which of these two to select**

---

### VOTING IS CLOSED.

### The new name for World Building chat is The Factory Floor

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks

Comment: I kind of feel like the "down votes" will not be counted is kind of weird. What's wrong with not supporting anything, or disliking something?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with not supporting but whether you like it or not, we only are counting upvotes

Comment: @Zizouz212, "first past the post" is the simplest way to run off between two candidates, you vote for one or you vote for the other. If you don't like one, vote for the other. Any other method just adds unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- **The Factory Floor**, From Slartibartfast line to Arthur "Welcome to our factory floor" in Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy

Comment: Note that someone downvoted this (against the rules), so the upvote count is actually 28, not 27. Not that that changes anything, but still.

Comment: @HDE226868 Your OCD could beat up my OCD :)

Answer (score 10):

**The World Workshop**

It implies that this is where you can finish building unfinished worlds (and the alliteration is a nice bonus as well.)