# What should the name of our chat be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

In a [previous question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/should-we-name-our-chat) it was agreed that we should have a new name for our chatroom and while a question [asking for suggestions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/a-name-for-our-chat) was made, our site has easily doubled in size since then. So at the suggestion of James and Monica;

What name suggestions do our users have for the Worldbuilding Chat?  One suggestion per answer, please, for ease of voting.

Comment: We should have a run-off of the top two options once voting slows down and have people just vote for one option

Comment: @James I  agree with that

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- **The Factory Floor**, From Slartibartfast line to Arthur "Welcome to our factory floor" in Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy

Comment: And meaningful even for people who don't know HHGttG -- nice.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I hadn't even thought of that great point

Comment: Not having read the Hitchikers' Guide, I don't understand the reference at all.

Comment: @fi12 The Factory Floor is where they build the planets

Comment: @fi12 Isn't it implied? The building _planets_ part no, but a "factory floor" is where things get assembled, put together, worked on. "_World Building - factory floor - where we World Build"_

Answer (score 15):

**The World Workshop**

It implies that this is where you can finish building unfinished worlds (and the alliteration is a nice bonus as well.)

Comment: Actually, it would work also without "world" for me. "Hey, what've you been doing? Well you know hanging 'round The Workshop."

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin you might want to post that as an alternative.

Comment: @MonicaCellio ok, [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3743/9685) it is. Though I presume it's too late already. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Just for completeness:

**Worldbuilders' General Chat**

For anyone who wants to vote to keep it the same.

Comment: Thank you for adding this, I completely forgot

Answer (score 6):

## Terra Forma

---

This is a play on words referencing both *terraforming*, aka world building, and *terra firma*, which literally means 'solid earth', but in common parlance refers to finally reaching the land that was your goal. This echoes the function of the site, Worlbuilding.SE, which helps people reach their goal of developing new worlds.

Answer (score 5):

#### The Workshop

A variant to [fi12's suggestion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3736/9685).

> Hey, what've you been doing? Well you know hanging 'round The Workshop.

Comment: [It's taken.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22025/the-workshop)

Answer (score 2):

- **Magrathea**, Who built Earth in The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy

Answer (score 2):

**The Green Dragon**

Of obvious Tolkien fame and also coincidentally a sort of unofficial headquarters for the [American Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Dragon_Tavern).

Comment: Sounds more like the chat room for rpg.sx, though. “Here be dragons”

Answer (score 1):

## House Of Illusions

Obvious. The perceptible world is an illusion and here, we endeavor to create believable illusions within the cosmic illusion.

Answer (score -2):

**The God, the Bard and the Loony**

Roles who are in the world-making and changing business, and an obvious Italo Western reference. (Improvements for the last one are welcome.)

Comment: I also thought about _(Great) Creatarea_ or _Creatarium_, the _Handwavery Inn_ and _A Godtogether_, but didn’t like them as much.

Answer (score -2):

## Worlds in Collision

After the classic SciFi novel and movie.

Answer (score -2):

## Words on Worlds

I like illiteration.

Answer (score -5):

**The Great Link**

the place where the founders get together. (in worldbuilding we are all founders of our own worlds, aren't we?)