# A Worldbuiding podcast/youtube channel

Tags: discussion, podcast

Afternoon (GTZ to you) world building.

A few of us were having a conversation in chat and the idea of a [World Building podcast/YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB-fq4eI--DHAwKJRIGhXqQ) came up.

The exact format and content are not defined at yet as the idea was quite literally just conceived.

At the most basic it would probably be similar in format to the SE podcast and the companion news posts that come with it.

---

So a few questions

1. Who is interested and in what way would you be interested? (add your name to the community wiki answer I will add)
2. What format/tools are available for this effort (another wiki answer)

Once we get a chance to nail these down we can get more into the details.

Thanks all.

---

### Finalized Information

- High level goal:  Podcasts similar to the SE ones, with a written summary posted to the blog and linking to the audio (or video) for the full episode.
- Technical solution:
- Branding information:  Blog Name - TBD, Blog Icon - TBD
- [Episode Planning Thread](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/world-building-podcast-episode-planning/3870#3870)

Comment: This is a great idea, but we do also have to think about the reality of doing this. The novelty *will* wear off after months of diligent work producing stuff gets you less than a hundred subscribers. If there are people who *will* work through that, it's okay. If we'll give up when it doesn't produce any rewards, it's not worth doing it.

Comment: That said, if we do get this off the ground I'd be glad to be involved.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I think the easiest way to help battle that is to focus on making it a discussion instead of prep work, and have responsibilities rotate. Technical-focused responsibilities can't rotate really, though.

Comment: It doesn't have to be weekly. It can be one-off presentations when something interesting is worked up.  Think of tge community theater production: once a season production.

Comment: unfortunatly, youtube considers having a channel about a website we do not own counts as copyright. So that is a no on youtube, but I feel a podcast is still a good idea

Comment: @TrEs-2b [Judaism.SE] has a Youtube account...

Comment: I Volunteer! I may not have participated on WorldBuilding.SE, but I'm a good speaker *I think*...

Comment: I'm definitely interested though I'm quite 'diffuse' so I'm not sure when can I join. But if you upload videos, I'll definitely check them later!

Comment: [Mentioned in the related sub on Reddit.](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/a-worldbuiding-podcast-youtube-channel?cb=1) Hope I can help some by it.

Comment: I think we can have the each of the host/speakers bring up questions that they think are interesting and have the group discuss and debate about it. Probably on a weekly basis . Also about the copyright issue, making a separate website for stack exchange world building (like a blog) where the podcast can be aired and posted on for future replays might be a good idea.

Comment: @Sky we already have a blog where we can embed video, though it needs to be hosted elsewhere.  The SE podcasts have audio plus a text summary; the blog would be a good place to do that summary.

Comment: I agree with Monica that we have a blog. That's actually the second attempt at it. And if it made a great start, it's struggling to get to its first birthday.  Why would a youtube channel prove any different? And why couldn't we turn some discussions on a blog-post? We essentially need to answer two questions: why do we need another platform? Why would it work better?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I am actually thinking the podcast would contribute (in the form of notes...or a synopsis to the blog.

Answer (score 6):

**Suggested Weekly Topics**

- Round table where each person brings in news articles/things they
  read that might be interesting from a world building PoV.
- One member guides the discussion on a specific topic and the others
  comment (this would rotate).
- Pick 1-3 questions that got a lot of attention since the last podcast
  and discuss the question and answers.
- Respond to comments, including any quickie world building questions.
- Talk about worlds built by site users

Answer (score 5):

Add your name and in what way you would like to be involved.

- *Name* **:** *Involvement*
- NexTerren: Host or Speaker, Video Editing/Technical Support
- TrEs-2b: Speaker, Idea generator
- ArtOfCode: Um. Anything but hosting? (I'm a sound engineer, so if we need audio edits, I can do those)
- John Długosz : Host, Speaker, Editing (Adobe Premiere), **Script writer/editor**.  I have decent studio mike at home.
- fi12: Script writer/editor, Video Concepts, Technical Support
- DaaaahWhoosh: Speaker
- James: Speaker and host
- Green: Guest and idea generator

Comment: i like very much the idea. sadly i have no sound/video experience. but i can research, moderate the comments on the video, answer them ...

Answer (score 5):

> **Existing toolchain**
> The tools used to edit the first episode were Audacity (for audio editing) and DaVinci Resolve (for video editing). Both are free. Audacity will run on almost any machine; DVR requires a reasonably powerful graphics card to run smoothly (and certainly to render the final cut at any sort of speed).

## Recommended Platforms/Tools

As of now we are probably only going to look at options that are free (or really cheap), so if there is cost involved please provide that information.

### Free

Please include what your platform/tool offers that would differentiate it from other options.

- Windows movie maker - while overly basic and simple, it is free and easy to learn and use.
- Blender - Highly powerful, and free. Not easy, but not hard.
- Audacity - Possibly for sound editing, it's a powerful, fairly easy to use, and free piece of software.
- OpenShot - non-linear video editing, if the user is not in Windows and/or doesn't mind working on GNU/Linux (the most recent version is meant to support Windows, too)
- Kdenlive - same as OpenShot, but available in GNU/Linux systems only (can use multiple cores for rendering the final video)
- Gimp - The equivalent of Photoshop in the free-software community (GPL license)
- [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) — A complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.  Command-line tools; various guis and wrappers are available separately, and it’s used as the engine in many other free/open tools.
- [VSee](https://vsee.com) — Video conferencing tools that allow multi-way conference calls and *recording*, and doesn’t stick its own logo over your screen.

### not so cheap

- nothing listed.

### super cheap

- Adobe Creative Suite, including Premere, After Effects, Audition, Photoshop, and Illustrator — pro tools used by many.

Comment: @JDługosz did you want to post the final selection info here?

Comment: Well, if I’m editing, I’ll be using Adobe and FFmpeg.

Answer (score 3):

**Preparation Checklist**

*This checklist assumes preparation for the first 3 episodes. After we get over this, I imagine forward movement will be more organic.*

*I think we should aim to have all of this list checked off or scheduled by end-of-month, August. This should either put us in a good point to move forward or determine that we can't move forward/there's not sufficient interest to move forward.*

✔ Select recording/call software: VSee
✔ Confirm host for the first 3 episodes (rotating)
.. ✔ James confirmed for host (1st)
.... ✔ Discussion topic picked
.... ✔ 1-3 Questions picked
.... ✔ 1-2 worlds picked
.... ✔ Select speakers/Organize recording time with speakers
.. ☐ ??? confirmed for host (2nd)
.... ☐ Discussion topic picked
.... ☐ 1-3 Questions picked
.... ☐ 1-2 worlds picked
.... ☐ Select speakers/Organize recording time with speakers
.. ☐ ??? confirmed for host (3rd)
.... ☐ Discussion topic picked
.... ☐ 1-3 Questions picked
.... ☐ 1-2 worlds picked
.... ☐ Select speakers/Organize recording time with speakers
✔ Confirm technical editor (video and sound): ArtOfCode
.. ✔ Select editing software: DaVinci Resolve (video), Audacity (audio)
.. ✔ Perform sound/technical test with *all prospective hosts*
☐ Produce episodes
.. ✔ First Episode
.... ✔ Record
.... ✔ Edit
.... ✔ Publish
.. ☐ Second Episode
.... ☐ Record
.... ☐ Edit
.... ☐ Publish
.. ☐ Third Episode
.... ☐ Record
.... ☐ Edit
.... ☐ Publish

Comment: If the hosts (when identified) could add a note about the types of topics they're most interested in, it could help other participants form up the best groups.  You'll get better conversation if everybody has some interest in the topic *de jour*, whether it's binary-star systems or dragons or time travel or whatever.

Comment: Please let me know when the password/email is needed

Comment: What's VSee?  (I don't see it on the software list.)  Client software?  A web-based thing?  Something else?

Comment: @MonicaCellio It seems that JDługosz is going to be our lead on everything technical. VSee is video conferencing software that he/his company develops, actually what's used by the ISS! He says he has access to the professional version, so he can host/record the actual cast, and then he'll edit it with Adobe tools.

Comment: @NexTerren cool.  Professional-grade tools are nice to have. :-)  (I was just wondering what this means for prospective participants, is all.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Apparently there's a free version, which all the speakers can use while he uses the professional version to host the calls. Since he's a literal developer of the software, I assume he knows what he's talking about as far as that model goes.

Comment: @JDługosz thanks for offering to host/provide support.

Answer (score 2):

### Podcast Branding

- The Factory Floor
- Podcast icon

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Can you add the icon/background images to this post please?

Answer (score 2):

For the name of the podcast, I suggest

## The World Workshop

I originally submitted it as a [possible chatroom name](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/what-should-the-name-of-our-chat-be) for Worldbuilding, and it received the second most number of votes.

It implies that this is where you can help finish building unfinished worlds (and the alliteration is a nice bonus as well.)

Comment: fi can you make this a community wiki answer please?