# World Building Podcast: Episode Planning

Tags: discussion, podcast

**Please post one answer per episode.**

**Basic Format:  Hosts feel free to modify to suit your needs.**

---

### Episode X:  Episode Title

---

**Things to do prior to the episode**

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item 4

---

**Host:**

- Name

**Guests/Co-hosts:**

- Name
- Name
- Optional

**Date/Time:**

- TBD

**Agenda**:

*Warmup:*

- *Name:* Description

*Main discussion topic:*  Name

- Bulleted Description
- Bulleted Description
- Bulleted Description

*Review of WB.SE recent/interesting questions:* To be selected by the host/guests/co-hosts once a date is set for the first cast.

- Question 1
- Question 2
- Question 3

*Discuss World(s):*

- World 1:  Owner, Name
- World 2:  Owner, Name

Comment: I think it's important that these podcasts aren't too long. If one item drags out longer than expected, hosts should be prepared to drop other items to keep within a rough timescale - half an hour, perhaps? That means hosts need to have an eye on the time.

Comment: I don't think half an hour is enough for a podcast. at the very least an hour should be needed.

Comment: @Sky I tend to agree with you but I think we will see how things go and adjust over time.

Comment: Just had a thought for a discussion topic for the podcast: origin of magic systems. Where they come from, why we make the rules the way we do, etc.

Answer (score 6):

### Episode 1:  The pilot (no pressure)

---

**Things to do prior to the episode**

- Come up with a name for the podcast:  Factory Floor
- Come up with an icon for the podcast:  Posted
- Cover art for the episode incorporating the podcast icon: Itll be a bigger version of the icon
- Ensure everyone gets the proper software installed: DONE (might add one additional tool)
- Ensure people have the proper hardware (mainly meaning a mic): ...James needs a new mic DONE
- Finalize the agenda (use the comments/chat for suggestions) I (James) am working on it currently, I will give it to everyone at least 2 or 3 days before
- Set a date and time DONE
- Get Audacity installed. James Done, Nex (?), Green (?), DaaaaWhoosh (?)

---

**Host:**

- James (me)

**Guests/Co-hosts:**

- Green
- Nex Terren
- DaaaahWhoosh

**Date/Time:**

- 2030 Central Time Thursday the 29th of September

**Agenda**:

*Introductions:*

I will ask these or similar questions during the introduction.

- Define world building
- What skills do you bring to world-building, what is your background
- Share something about yourself that will make people remember you.

*Warmup:*

- *The alignment game:* Bring up a random well known personality and then discuss where they fall on the alignment scale.  This is simply a warm up and to get the discussion juices flowing.  I will have a few names in my pocket we may do 2 or 3 depending on how long it takes.

  - Sun Tzu
  - Arthur Dent
  - Mystery Name 1
  - Mystery Name 2

*Main discussion topic:*  What got us into world building/what draws us to it and what we are working on.  James will generate questions to facilitate the question.

- What made you interested in world building in the first place?  Not the site, the concept.
- Who is the best world builder (author, game designer etc) and you can't choose Tolkien.
- What are you building currently and how far along are you?

  - Take turns describing

Discuss each person's efforts.

*Discuss World(s):*

- World 1:  James, ...it doesn't really formally have a name.  If you want to use this during the conversation feel free:  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-worlds-are-you-currently-building/3687#3687
- World 2:  George Lucas (Disney if you prefer), Star Wars

*Review of WB.SE recent/interesting questions:* To be selected by the host/guests/co-hosts once a date is set for the first cast.

- [How do you establish identity when people can change their appearance at will?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/how-do-you-establish-identity-when-people-can-change-their-appearance-at-will)
- In Crimson Skies (an alternate Earth with technology somewhere between our WWI and WWII) a small mercenary band uses a Zeppelin as a mobile base of operations, and further as a launching spot for their aircraft (1-3 in number). How feasible is this concept? How could we make it work better? What advantages does it have? What precautions/tactics would needed to be used for such an airship base?
- [Would ritual cannibalism of the dead lead to issues with disease?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20982/would-ritual-cannibalism-of-the-dead-lead-to-issues-with-disease/20988#20988)
- How does one motivate Green to show up to the Podcast on time?

Comment: I assume hitler is out for the warmup.

Comment: Is the "alignment scale" the same one employed by Dungeons and Dragons, or something else?

Comment: @Frostfyre Yep, the DnD 9 alignment grid

Comment: For the worlds, you could have James world of seminosia. Not only is he the host so he can clarify more details but it's pretty fleshed out on http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-worlds-are-you-currently-building?rq=1

Comment: I suggest for the worlds discussion we go down the list in http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-worlds-are-you-currently-building?rq=1 and cover most of them. If the user has not given enough detail we could ask for them to flesh it out either in chat or in a meta post.

Comment: I propose the podcast be named 'DaaaahWhoosh', the icon be my avatar, and the cover art also be my avatar.

Comment: Why not take hot question toppics from the site and discuss that ?

Comment: @Magic-Mouse That's already listed man...

Comment: I [suggested a possible name](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/a-worldbuiding-podcast-youtube-channel/3902#3902) for the podcast.

Comment: I'd be down as a possible guest sometime in the future.

Comment: Where can this podcast be listened?

Comment: @AlbertMasclans We just (finally) recorded episode 1 last night, and sent the files to our editing guy. When he's finished with it, we'll upload it to Youtube and provide a link.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans "editing guy" here. I've finished the final edit; now we're waiting on configuring the YT channel. Soon (tm).

Answer (score 4):

### Episode 2:  Aaaand cut!

---

**Things to do prior to the episode**

- Monica: borrow webcam (done)
- Monica and ?: verify Monica's sound before 'cast
- item 3
- item 4

---

**Host:**

- James

**Guests/Co-hosts:**

- Green
- Nex Terran
- Monica

**Date/Time:**

- 1 Nov 2016 8:30 PM CT

**Agenda**:

*Introduction:* Introduce people and the podcast...and stuff.

*Warmup:*

- *Name:* Playing God(s) (the title needs work)

*Misordered Technology*

The following three technologies come to practicle, widespread fruitation roughly at the same time (within the last 15 years or so)...

*Wireless Telegraphy. Systems for transmitting information between people have been around for centuries, perhaps millennia. Telegraph signals got a speed boost in the U.S. from Samuel Morse and Alfred Vail. Wireless telegraphy as invented by Guglielmo Marconi, later evolving into radio, set information free from wires.*

*The airplane. For “the Realization of an age-long dream” he gave the laurels of success to the Wright brothers, but apart from its military use reserved judgment on the utility of the invention: “It presents the least commercial utility of all the inventions considered.”*

*The Linotype machine. The Linotype machine enabled publishers—largely newspapers—to compose text and print it much faster and cheaper. It was an advance as large as the invention of the printing press itself was over the painstaking handwritten scrolls before it.*

*From "What Are the 10 Greatest Inventions of Our Time?" by By Daniel C. Schlenoff on November 1, 2013, Scientific American*

...But gunpowder has yet to see widespread, practicle applicaitons.

*Main discussion topic:*  Interview with Monica on her world and use of the world building website.

- Please introduce your world at a high level

  - Who are these people and where do they live?
  - Introduce your deities
- Talk about how you used WB to build it
- Bulleted Description

*Review of WB.SE recent/interesting questions:* To be selected by the host/guests/co-hosts once a date is set for the first cast.  Proposed: We examine good questions closed as "too broad" as there is plenty of space for discussion and we are smart people. (Also, we have lots of [options](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/560632/most-interesting-closed-questions))

- [Can you add a mini moon to Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/can-you-add-a-mini-moon-to-earth) (Monica)
- [What would a battle between supercomputers be like with the battleground being the internet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27231/what-would-a-battle-between-supercomputers-be-like-with-the-battleground-being-t) (Green)
- [If magic is real, can it be true that rational scientific thought should exclude it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/if-magic-is-real-can-it-be-true-that-rational-scientific-thought-should-exclude) And more generally: In a setting where 'magic' is undeniably real, what does this mean for its relationalship to science? (Nex)
- [How can I develop names for my fantasy land?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48622/how-can-i-develop-names-for-my-fantasy-land/48626#48626)

*Discuss World(s):*

- World 1:  Green, Programmable Magic Systems
- World 2:  Owner, Name

Comment: For #2, maybe consider doing some workshopping, like sometimes happens in chat -- somebody brings a real, perhaps vague, worldbuilding problem he's trying to solve, and the group discusses and helps refine it and maybe even comes up with some clever solutions.  The kind of thing that works poorly for Q&A can work well for interactive conversation.  Just a thought.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I have a tradition at work at lunch where I ask a "question of the day".  Generally, good WB questions make for poor discussion.  However, questions closed as "too broad" are often fertile grounds for discussion.  In short, the workshopping approach seems like a good one to me.

Comment: Right, I meant the kinds of questions that we close on main can be good for workshopping discussions.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, sorry.  I meant to confirm your assertion with my own experience.  We are in agreement :)

Comment: Stashing this here for now: interesting-to-me questions I might bring up: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/can-you-add-a-mini-moon-to-earth, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37777/the-evolution-of-neon-kittens/37815#37815.

Comment: Questions related to *The Sisters' War*: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/71/28, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/20876/28, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4594/28.

Comment: Why not name the part where you "warm up" "Playing God"?

Answer (score 2):

### Episode 3:  By the Gods, A Third Episode!

---

**Things to do prior to the episode**

- Art gets vsee installed
- Each person select a WB site question and post it (and the link) below ...we probably won't use all of them.
- Consider something you will recommend at the end of the episode.  Try to follow the technology theme.
- Figure out a warm-up game that won't take 45 minutes.
- Green share a preview of the magical programming world with the panel

---

**Host:**

- James

**Guests/Co-hosts:**

- Green
- Nex Terren
- ArtOfCode

**Date/Time:**

- Saturday, February 4th 1300 Central Time (1900 UTC)

**Agenda**:  The theme for this episode will be technology.

*Introduction:*  Welcomes and introduce Art

*Warmup:*

*Main discussion topic:*  Green's world.  A magical programming school

- Introduce the world
- Explain how magic and programming coexist
- I am sure we will think of more

*Review of WB.SE recent/interesting questions:* To be selected by the host/guests/co-hosts once a date is set for the first cast.

- Question 1
- [What would it take to build a ship capable of crossing the Pacific?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25272/what-would-it-take-to-build-a-ship-capable-of-crossing-the-pacific)
- [In what war would one modern military vehicle make a difference?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/in-what-war-would-one-modern-military-vehicle-make-a-difference)
- [Herbivores in an all-animal army](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/what-good-are-herbivores-in-an-animal-army)
- [Truth Stones](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62572/truth-stone-effects-on-the-justice-system-and-criminal-world)

**Recommendations:**

Come up with a book, site, or some other resource. Try to keep it on theme.

Comment: You should make the discussion of Green's "programmable magic" world the first main item this time, as it's fallen off the end twice now.

Comment: I have been thinking about working it in with a theme I have in mind (I think we need themes for focus...we can chat later) its late :)

Comment: For questions from the site: in podcast #2 these discussions took ~15, 8, 5, and 8 minutes.  Maybe we want to discuss fewer questions per podcast in the future, assuming we also have a warmup, a feature, and some sort of round-robin recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

### Episode 4:  Episode Title (We don't know yet)

---

**Things to do prior to the episode**

- Identify a guest
- Identify a main topic
- Get the guest set up with the technology stuff
- Schedule data and time

---

**Host:**

- James

**Guests/Co-hosts:**

- Green
- Nex
- TBD

**Date/Time:**

- TBD

**Agenda**:

*Warmup:*

- *Questions for WB users:* [Visit this thread to add your suggestions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/want-to-contribute-a-question-to-the-podcast-or-try-to-stump-the-panel)

*Main discussion topic:*  TBD, [feel free to offer suggestions here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/world-building-podcast-potential-topics-themes).

- Bulleted Description
- Bulleted Description
- Bulleted Description

*Review of WB.SE recent/interesting questions:* Questions will be selected once we know what the main topic will be so we can maintain the theme.

- Question 1
- Question 2
- Question 3

*Discuss World(s):* We don't usually get to this...

- World 1:  Owner, Name
- World 2:  Owner, Name