# World Building Podcast: Potential Topics/Themes

Tags: discussion, podcast

We have gotten the second podcast up and posted (still doing some clean up in the description etc.) but we have been discussing making the episodes more focused and wanted to gather a list of potential topics/themes that could be used going forward.

I will post a community wiki answer shortly where we can keep track of the list.  The podcast team will pull ideas from here when we are planning future episodes.

Thanks for participating.  Feel free to add your name to your idea so we can give you credit.

Answer (score 6):

**World Building for Table Top Gaming** -- *James*

**From the crowd (answering community questions)** -- *James*

**Geography and mapmaking** -- *James*

**Why we make magic systems the way we do** -- *Frostfyre*

**Alien biology and creature design** -- TrEs-2b

**World Building Setting Tropes (Series?)** -- *Nex Terren*

- Space Opera
- Steam Punk
- High Fantasy
- ...

**How Diversity (Gender, Nationality, etc.) in Our Community Provides Better Questions & Answers** -- Mikey

**Politics** - *James*

Answer (score 1):

Ideas we have already used:

1. Technology (General)
2. xxx
3. xxx
4. xxx